# How to swich html files

Tags: windows, shell

I use the following script that I open as a hyperlink from PowerPoint. By the script a full screen .HTML file is opened. Is it possible to add to the script that after pressing a key on the keyboard opens another .HTML file? Many thanks.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.run "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -kiosk file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/prezentace/file.html",0,False
```

After advice:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.run "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"" -kiosk file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/10_semestr/diplomka_prezentace/file.html",0,False
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    document.location="https://google.com";
};
</script>
hit any key and go to Google
</body>
</html>
```

I got this error: a command was expected, the mistake during the compilation.

[image]

Comment: Once you open firefox the keyboard focus will be on the file.html page. If file.html is under your control, probably you can add Javascript to open another URL on keypress.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by adding Javascript? The .HTML is written by python.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can think of is that file.html contains something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    document.location="https://google.com";
};
</script>
hit any key and go to Google
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I am an absolute biginner. I have the *.vbs script in the question to open .HTML file. Where this script belong to? Thank you

Comment: You are opening a local file `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\prezentace\file.html` from Firefox.

You can edit this file and add all inclusive between <script></script> right after the <body> tag.

Comment: I got the error. I added that to my question.

Comment: Hard to explain you this "solution". You don't have to change the .vbs, you have to change the .html in that way that it includes the <script>. That depends if you have control over this file. As long as I can see, it is a static html on your disk. So you can edit (notepad) this file and adding the (Javascript) <script> right after <body>. Sorry, cannot help for more.